# How to balance player cooperation in "Don't Rest Your Head"

Tags: dont-rest-your-head

In the game "Don't Rest Your Head" players can add their Discipline dice to that of a colleague to support their effort. (Technically, they add their *successes* and do not affect the *strength*.)  I am going to have a game of four players, who are motivated to help each other - they are all hunted by the same enemy.  If they pooled all of their Discipline dice, that would make 12 dice - comparable to the Pain level of the Biggest Bads in the book!  They would have no danger of getting Exhaustion or Madness results, either.

I realize that DRYH is not optimized for team play.  Is there a simple and balanced fix for running a four player game?

Answer (score 2):

### Not contributing to domination is a bigger deal than you think it is.

> Regardless, everyone who participates in the effort is vulnerable to whatever dominates - which can mean that multiple protagonists could all find themselves checking off responses, or gaining exhaustion. (*Helping*, p. 19)

Exhaustion dominates? Four more exhaustion.

Madness dominates? Not only four responses, but *playing out* four responses.

Pain dominates? Four Despair.

Pain **wins**? Exhaustion for some, berserk rage for others!

And if you the GM have some Despair rattling around already, you can put your thumb on the scale of what dominates, too.

I mean, yes, if you're a protagonist staring down the barrel of a fully loaded Mother When, all of those are probably better alternatives than trying to deal with Pain 12 on your lonesome, but overcoming Pain 12 doesn't mean you end Mother When, just like that. It means you get what you were after out of the exchange.

Mother When is Pain 12 when she goes to the grocery store and tries to get the last thing in the rotisserie case, and winning just means you grab it instead, which is still pretty great when it's your estranged brother who caught on to the shady backroom dealings at JojaPharm.

But, yes, **if** four protagonists are all working together, **and** never need to split up to do all the things they want to do, **and** never need to roll Madness to do anything a normal human couldn't feasibly do, **and never lose**, the GM isn't going to have a lot for Despair to find purchase on.

Comment: But in this case there aren't any Exhaustion or Madness dice.  They can simply use their Discipline dice.   And you can't use Despair coins to add a "6" to a pool that has no dice to begin. (Your point about Pain is helpful!)

Comment: Right, I've added a couple bits, but the summary is "only if you let them and also they get lucky".

Answer (score 1):

## Alternate Solution From Supplemental Book

The supplement *Don't Lose Your Mind* gives an optional rule allowing assisting players to add their Madness dice (as many as they want)

> Here’s something to consider: instead of having players use their Discipline dice when help an ally out, set that rule aside and instead reach for the jolly candy-like Madness dice—maybe as much as all six of them. But just like with the Discipline-helping rule, both helper and helped will be subject to the results of what dominates; and in this rule, the Madness dice from both characters combine to determine what dominates. (Black, p.63)

Comment: Especially for the dual-natured game you've been talking about in other questions, it might be really interesting to limit help to Madness in the City Slumbering, and to Discipline in the Mad City (though also the Permanent Madness dice, which will still pool together to dominate).